# How to specify image to lxc

Tags: ubuntu, lxc

When I run

```
lxc image list images:ubuntu/noble
```

I get a table, of which line 2 is

```
| ubuntu/noble (7 more)             | ce692961c504 | yes    | Ubuntu noble amd64 (20231111_07:42) | x86_64       | CONTAINER       | 120.29MiB  | Nov 11, 2023 at 12:00am (UTC) |
```

I wish to launch a container using this image. I have tried every variation of

```
lxc launch ubuntu:noble  europa
```

That I can think of and not yet found the magic incantation.They all error with "Error: Failed instance creation: Failed getting remote image info: Failed getting image: The requested image couldn't be found"

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.